# Symfony Ignore Directory in web/

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony1

In an symfony project, is there any way to exclude a directory from being processed.

For example, I want to run a seperate php program in mysite.com/other_app

How can I exclude web/other_app folder from being processed by the symfony controller.

I've tried using

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/other_app/(.*)$

and

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Symfony still processes the other_app which obviously isn't going to work properly. Any suggestions.Do I need to modify htaccess in other_app/.htaccess as well?

Also, let me add. When I access just the directory mysite.com/other_app I get the correct content. If I try and access anything below that, I get problems.

**This works:**
mysite.com/other_app

**This does not:**
mysite.com/other_app/page1

In the logs I get an error: 
**Action "other_app/page1" does not exist**. Or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. The .htaccess of the sub directory also needs to be modified.

In web/.htaccess use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

In the sub directory, web/other_app/.htaccess use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /other_app/index.php [QSA,L]
```

This will work for wordpress and most any other php app that you want to run on a symfony site, but don't want to deal with trying to hack it into the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```