# Access wordpress blog in Symfony

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, symfony-2.8

I have setup a wordpress blog inside a directory called 'blog' in Symfony web folder (root). But I cannot access it from the browser and I get the following error:

```
"Forbidden"
"You don't have permission to access /blog/ on this server."
```

My site: www.example.com (/web/ <- symfony)

My blog: www.example.com/blog/ (/web/blog/ <- wordpress directory)

There is no route in the routing.yml that points to /blog.

How can I set up my wordpress blog inside the web folder and access it on browser?

PS:

**app.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**app_dev.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

//umask(0000);

/*if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1'), true) || PHP_SAPI === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}*/

require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**web/.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

#Options FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**web/blog/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please show your app.php and app_dev.php in order to help you

Comment: @FranckGamess Appended to the question above. Please recheck. Thanks.

Comment: My bad, I don't think **app_dev.php** and **app.php** will help to resolve. Do you have a **.htaccess** file in the web folder? Any apache configuration?

Comment: @FranckGamess I have a .htaccess file in the web folder. It is the default .htaccess file that comes with the project setup.

Answer (score 2):

Technically this does not depend on Symfony.

The first step of routing takes place at the level of the webservers (apache, nginx, symfony's inbuilt testing server).

These are configured to send every request made to the application to `public/index.php`.

From there Symfony picks up the request and determines what controller is to full-fill it.

If you would now go and tell the app to ignore the request it would need to forward it to the sub-folder which would likely result in undesired behaviour somewhere along the line.

So, since you want your sub-folder to be ignored you really want to set this rule before the request ever hits Symfony.

In other words - you should look at excluding the sub-folder from being passed to `public/index.php` at server level.

Here is an answer from way back that covers this for Apache using `.htaccess` - [Symfony Ignore Directory in web/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728265/symfony-ignore-directory-in-web)

Comment: I agree with this answer

Comment: Updated the question with both htaccess file contents.

Comment: In `web/.htaccess` try putting `RewriteRule ^(blog)($|/) - [L]` after `RewriteEngine On`. That should make symfony ignore `/blog/` - in theory :-)

Comment: Did so. but still no. :-(